# Is shows No Such directory what shall i do i'm new to programming please hlep

Tags: c++, build, compiler-errors, directory, turtle-graphics

This is IITB simplecpp i am trying to run the program  but it shows the following issue..if anyone an help with it i'm new to this.

[image]

Comment: you miss . in your include, put simple.cpp

Comment: Don't forget the space either: `#include <simple.cpp>`, generally `<` and `>` are reserved for libraries and `"` are used for your own files so `#include "simple.cpp"` is likely what you are looking for.  Finally, `.cpp` files aren't included, so you likely meant `#include "simple.hpp"`

Comment: First of all, you seem to have some project problems. Secondly, who told you to `#include <simplecpp>`? What is this `simplecpp`? Where is the file `simplecpp` located?

Comment: And *don't* include source files (files ending in e.g. `.cpp`). Please invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and learn the difference between *header* files (which you include) and *source* files (which you build).

Comment: https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure/

Comment: @Brandon The library's header is actually called "simplecpp". The name is not the problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The library's header is actually called "simplecpp". The name is not the problem.

Comment: There is a problem with your library installation or your IDE configuration. Which version did you install?

Comment: I would be more concerned about the first line: `=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===` and start by sorting that out - like having a known compiler build an executable.

Comment: Have to told Code::Blocks where to find the library?